The WordPress page does not complete the loading when using $_POST
When the form is submitted it will load ok if I comment out $autoin = $_POST[autoin] and $colnum = $_POST[cnumin] The count returned is = to 4.
This is the form:
<form class="" action="https://mypage" method="POST">
     CVS File to upload: <input id="cvsfi" name ="cvsfi" type = file required/>
     Check the box if auto increment: <input id="autoin" name ="autoin" type = checkbox>
     Column number for key: <input id="cnumi" name="cnumi" size="2" type="number" required/>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

This is the page:
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Template uploadcsv
 *
 * @package Longevity
 * 
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">

<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
if( isset($_POST['action']) != 0)
{
    echo "No form submitted";
    goto GetOut1;
}
echo count($_POST);
GoTo GetOut1;
$csvin = $_POST['cvsfi'];
$autoin = $_POST[autoin];
$colnum = $_POST[cnumin];
GetOut1: 
?> 
        
</div>
    
<?php get_footer(); ?>

I tried $_POST and $_GET. The page hangs on both.
